# Tensor algebra identity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, tensor-calculus

In our course we took the following formula:

$$F^\mu{}_\lambda\partial_{\mu}F^{\lambda \nu}=\frac 1 2 F_{\mu \lambda}\partial^{\mu}F^{\lambda \nu} + \frac 1 2F_{\lambda \mu}\partial^{\lambda}F^{\mu \nu}$$

It wasn't derived, we simply said that we utilize what we know about the covariant form of Maxwell's equations, in this case:

$$\partial^{\mu}F^{\lambda \nu}+ \partial^{\lambda}F^{\nu \mu} + \partial^{\nu}F^{\mu \lambda} $$

I did the following thing:

$$F^\mu{}_\lambda\partial_{\mu}F^{\lambda \nu}=F^{\mu}_{\ \ \lambda}\partial^{\pi}g_{\pi \mu}F^{\lambda \nu}=F_{\pi \lambda}\partial^{\pi}F^{\lambda \nu}=F_{\mu \lambda}\partial^{\mu}F^{\lambda \nu}$$

Then by taking into consideration the formula for the covariant Maxwell eq. and simply adjusting the symbols to the appropriate ones that I am utilizing here , you could write the eq. as:

$$F^\mu{}_\lambda\partial_{\mu}F^{\lambda \nu}=F_{\mu \lambda}(- \partial^{\lambda}F^{\nu \mu} -\partial^{\nu}F^{\mu \lambda})$$

But this result has nothing to do with what I am supposed to derive. I don't know where the $\frac 1 2$ constant comes from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've written down your equation correctly, then it's simply a matter of:

$$F_{ab}\partial^{a}F^{bc}$$

has two dummy indices, $a$ and $b$.  You can freely swap their names, because they are summed over, so whether you call them $a$ or $b$ doesn't mean anything, as long as the place where you have the bottom index matches the place where you have the top index

So trivially, the above term is the same as

$$F_{ba}\partial^{b}F^{ac}$$

when, then, is, of course, the same as

$$\frac{1}{2}F_{ab}\partial^{a}F^{bc} + \frac{1}{2}F_{ba}\partial^{b}F^{ac}$$

Comment: I was aware of the dummy indices, but because these indices were : 2 of them in one term and 2 other terms had 1 each I thought that one can't consider them as dummy. But apparently that is not important, important is to see which indices are similar and swapped, one up and one down, right? Anyway thank you, I was able to solve it

Comment: @imbAF if it makes life easier to think about, you could think about "call a  x and call b y", which is just renaming.  then, "call x b, and y a" which is just another renaming.  The only important thing is not changing the order of anything.  In this case, it means, keeping the first index of $F$ contracted on the partial derivative, and the second index contracted on the first raised index of $F$

Comment: And don't feel bad, it's easy to get lost in the index gymnastics when one is starting with this.  And people who have been doing it a long time forget that there is even anything non-trivial happening.

Comment: I understand, and yes it has to do with practice. But I am careful to understand every little detail. Btw Jerry, I have one additional question, a bit unrelated to this. Do you know any pdf or links which have information regarding the flux of a moving charged particle with constant velocity?